# Execution behaviour of cron

Tags: linux, cron, scheduling

I want to schedule a cron so as to avoid running at midnight. I was thinking a period of 7 minutes.

Now, I figured out with 7 minutes of interval, the last cron schedule for a particular day would be at 23:55 PM in the night.

So, here is my question, will the cron be rolled over and start its execution again at 00:07 AM the next day, or will continue its existing period and will execute at 00:02 AM?

We are using `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)`.

Here is my cron configuration

```
*/7 * * * * sh /home/dragon/work/pling.sh | tee /home/dragon/work/pling_`date +"\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M\%S"`.log
```

Comment: Which `cron` do you use? I'd like to see how they define "interval".

Comment: yeah, I was just about to say that. if you don't know which cron you use, we can probably tell you based on distro. the easiest will be Arch Linux, OpenSUSE (IIRC), and RHEL-based distros, including Fedora and CentOS. those use `systemd-cron`.

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Using an asterisk indicates the entire range of valid values, in this case 0-59.  */7 is telling cron "Run for every minute between 0 and 59, with steps of 7". This runs at 00:00, 00:07, …, 00:56, 01:00, 01:07, …  Crond runs every minute and checks to see which entries match.  It doesn't care about the last time it ran, and won't keep a tally (IE running at 00:56 and then again at 01:03.. that would get insane after a couple days)

To tell it not to run at midnight, you can do the following:

```
# Run from 1AM to 11PM hours, every 7th minute  
*/7 1-23 * * * sh /home/dragon/work/pling.sh | tee /home/dragon/work/pling_`date +"\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M\%S"`.log  
# Account for the first hour, don't run at midnight, but every other 7th minute:  
7-59/7 0 * * * sh /home/dragon/work/pling.sh | tee /home/dragon/work/pling_`date +"\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M\%S"`.log
```